# Redirect url opens device browser

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Working with browser plugin in ionic 3 and i need to open the browser web-view only inside ionic app and not to open external browsers, so i did like this

```
constructor(    public iab: InAppBrowser) {}
url = "https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/";

    options : InAppBrowserOptions = {'location':'no'    };

        this.iab.create(this.url,'_self' , this.options )
```

Even if i set target to "_blank" the link gets opened in an external browser

But in some devices the url gets opened in an browser could someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html

```
<ion-content  >
   <iframe  sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts"  *ngIf="!loading" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:none; " [src]="yourURl"></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

Add this line in your constructor

```
 this.yourURl=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(URL_link_here);
```

Comment: Does play store suspend app if i use the above

Comment: No, because I have multiple apps on app store as well as play store with above logic.

Comment: in my app i have only a web view with not other functionality but my app got rejected because of web-view content violation and spam policy. could you give me some hints or share me the webview app links